# How to upload a file from Tinymce in a angular application?

Tags: angular, tinymce-4

I've started a project using Angular 4, together with Material Design. In the project I would like to use TinyMce 4 to be able to write "news".

I have tried to follow this example https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/file-picker/  but gets a error on line reading

```
const file = this.files[0];
```

The error looks like:

```
 Property 'files' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
```

I am new to javascript so I really would appreciate some help.

//lg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem.

```
const file = this.files[0];
```

should be

```
const file = input.files[0];
```

I don't know why it works in the example mentioned above,, but this change made it for me.